# Amazon sns : Create platform end point through HTTP calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, https, amazon-sns

I am trying to implement push notifications for mobile application using AWS SNS.
Our application does not support any of the methods(node js, python etc) mentioned in AWS website to access AWS SDK. So I need to call Amazon SNS api with HTTP calls directly instead of other methods.

Is there any way to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the HTTP API is well documented.  I use the HTTP API to send notifications.  Getting the HTTP headers just right can be a bit frustrating at first, but the responses from the endpoint often give you pretty good hints.  Sadly there aren't a lot of easy to follow code examples so it might take some time to get it just right.

Here's a link to the API:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/Welcome.html

Some good info here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/CommonParameters.html

How to sign an HTTP API request:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html